# How to spoof site referrer?

Tags: php, javascript, http, referrer

I have 2 pages :

1.php and 2.php

When the user arrives on 2.php, i want to show on 2.php that the user is arriving from **google.com** and NOT from 1.php

I tried spoofing the header of 2.php using

```
<?php
header();
?>
```

when i do a javascript `document.write(document.referrer);` it shows me 1.php

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what is the reason for doing this?

Comment: i just got 2 down votes due to pointing your question is conflict with what u trying to accomplish, can u show us what is your actual intention ?

Comment: just wanted to see if i could fool the browser into thinking it came from pageX when they came from pageY

Comment: Sounds like you need to store a flag in the session, so that you can tell on page 2 that the user entered via page 1

Comment: if such case, u should enhance your question by NOT telling us `i want to show on 2.php`, show is kind of like print to me, am I mis-interpret something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The http referrer is a request header. The server (PHP) can only set response headers.

Thus the only way to spoof a referrer is for the client to do it, usually via some sort of browser plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to test a referrer check? The easiest way to do it — no browser plug-in required — is to use a `javascript:` URL:

```
javascript:location="http://your.web.server/2.php"
```

Open `http://www.google.com/` and paste that into the address bar. It will open `2.php`, with the referrer being `http://www.google.com/`. The only problem I am aware of is that this does not work on Internet Explorer 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP CURL to call the page and fake a referring URL, user agent, and other variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use cURL:

```
curl --referer http://fakereferrer.com http://targetwebsite.com
```